# Forex trading algorithm doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, algorithm, trading, forex

Hi I'm trying to implement a forex trading algorithm using the OANDA api. I created an account in OANDA and the key was generated.

When following code was implemented, I didn't recive any error, but seems that the data are not getting fetched.

```
"""
The main file that will evolve into our trading library
"""
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import v20


OANDA_ACCESS_TOKEN = ""
OANDA_ACCOUNT_ID = '' #put your access id here 

def main():
    print("------ System online -------", datetime.now())
    latest_price_time = (datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(seconds=15)).isoformat('T')+'Z'

    api = v20.Context(
            'api-fxpractice.oanda.com',
            '443',
            token=OANDA_ACCESS_TOKEN)

    response = api.pricing.get(
                    OANDA_ACCOUNT_ID,
                    instruments='EUR_USD',
                    since=latest_price_time,
                    includeUnitsAvailable=False)

    print(response)

    prices = response.get("prices", 200)
    print (prices)
    if len(prices):
        buy_price = prices[0].bids[0].price 

        print("Buy at " + str(buy_price))

        response = api.order.market(
            OANDA_ACCOUNT_ID,
            instrument='EUR_USD',
            units=5000)

        print("Trading id: " + str(response.get('orderFillTransaction').id))
        print("Account Balance: " + str(response.get('orderFillTransaction').accountBalance))
        print("Price: " + str(response.get('orderFillTransaction').price))

    else:
        print(response.reason)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the output that I received.

> ------ System online ------- 2019-04-27 13:08:32.531057 Method = GET Path =
>   https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com:443/v3/accounts/101-011-11099167-001/pricing?instruments=EUR_USD&since=2019-04-27T07%3A38%3A17.531057Z&includeUnitsAvailable=False Status = 200 Reason = OK Content-Type = application/json
>
> [] OK

But when the above path was accessed I'm receiving the following error.

[image]

Comment: Sounds pretty self explanatory to me. You'll need to take it up with the oanda.com folks to see why your account isn't authorised to perform your action.

Comment: Other than that there no issue seems any issue right?

Comment: Hard to say if some other issue might show up once you've fixed this one.

Comment: ok I will check this first... Thnks

Comment: Hi Brunns. Do I need to do any payments to acess this data. I just created a free account and then generated the token and it was used

Comment: I don't know anything about oanda.com. I simply read the error message.

Answer (score 1):

The link in the error message needs the authentication header, that is not a public link only you with the proper token can see it. Try it with [postman](https://www.postman.com) and add the authentication to the request header.

```
prices = ctx.pricing.get('ACCOUNT_ID', instruments='EUR_USD').get('prices')
print(prices[0])
```

and the result is something like this:

```
type: PRICE
instrument: EUR_USD
time: '2021-12-03T22:00:00.103275355Z'
status: non-tradeable
tradeable: false
bids:
- price: 1.13145
  liquidity: 10000000
asks:
- price: 1.13245
  liquidity: 10000000
closeoutBid: 1.13145
closeoutAsk: 1.13245
quoteHomeConversionFactors:
  positiveUnits: 1.0
  negativeUnits: 1.0
```

On the other side, you dont really need the latest price if you buy on market.